# iPhone: how to upload Photos to Twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am working on Twitter app for iPhone; in this app, I am using `MGTwitterEngine` and OAuth. I want to upload photos to a user's profile; could you please guide me how to add this feature to my Twitter app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will do: http://www.getsharekit.com/. It supports many other social services too, so you could potentially upload images to other networks too :)